# Cant download artifacts from gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Pls help!

I install gitlab server. And need download artifacts after pipline done.
I genereate Personal Access Tokens from my user profile

and try this:

```
curl -O --location --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 123NU9wDXSy1GFE7tiYF" "http://gitlab.local/cas/v-ui/-/jobs/1533/artifacts"
```

in output file i see only http text, with registration form.

Where i`m wrong ?

Comment: as i know this not working, so that i`m solve my problem add pipline step , that copy artifacts by ssh

Answer (score 0):

as i know this not working, so that i`m solve my problem add pipline step , that copy artifacts by ssh